# Formulas limits

Tags: formula-field

I'm trying to write a formula in the custom field Aging__c, in the standard WorkOrder object as follows:

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(DATEVALUE(EndDate))), Today - DATEVALUE(StartDate), DATEVALUE(EndDate) - DATEVALUE(StartDate))
```

But I'm having a limit error saying that I'm using more than 10.000 characters.
I tried a lot of diferent variations of this same formula but always ended with 8.000+ 10.000+ characters error, any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually occurs because you have too many formula fields. You're going to have delete one or more formulas, or use an alternative means of setting the value, such as using a workflow field update to set a normal date field. You can read more about that error in [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005456&type=1).